# diff two files and keep just new or changed lines

Tags: file, bash, diff

I would like to write a bash script or a few shell commands that solves my problem.  I have two files, old.txt, new.txt.  I would like to produce a file, diff.txt, that has only the lines that have changed or are new.  For instance if I had:

old.txt:

```
Sierra
Tango
Oscar
Victor
Whiskey
Yankee
```

new.txt:

```
Sierra
Tango
Echo
Osc__ar
Victor
Uniform
Whiskey
Yan__kee
```

I would want a diff.txt that looks like this:

```
Echo
Osc__ar
Uniform
Yan__kee
```

For perspective, I am writing this script to help me create a differential Motorolla S2 record for loading programs over serial port to an embedded computer.  I know bash fairly well, I just don't know where to get started.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{old[$0];next};!($0 in old)' old.txt new.txt
Echo
Osc__ar
Uniform
Yan__kee
```

Comment: This is the answer that can deal with large files (i.e. 30k lines in my case); the grep answer consumed too many resources.

Answer (score 16):

```
$ grep -v -f old.txt new.txt
Echo
Osc__ar
Uniform
Yan__kee
```

Comment: Awesome, this works, but if either file has empty lines the output is empty.  Also for the full file I want to diff I get "grep: Invalid back reference"

Comment: @portforwardpodcast Do you have anything that could be interpreted as a regular expression in your old file?

Comment: Ya I totally do.  Lots of slashes and starts and dots etc.  I think awk is the way to go for me :)

Comment: You can also use '-F' flag for grep - it makes it to ignore any regex, so slashes/dots etc. will be treated as plain text. In total you'll get 'grep -F -v -f old.txt new.txt'

Comment: This looks nifty, but it burns massive CPU / RAM for large files when compared to the [awk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9510294/667301).  This answer ran for over two minutes and burned many 100s of MB of RAM while munching on a 30k-line file before I bailed on it.  By comparison, the awk answer ran in less than a second

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to only the new lines and changed lines using `diff`:

```
$ cat file.txt file2.txt 
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 5
$ cat file2.txt 
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4b
line 5
line 6

$  diff --changed-group-format='***%>' --unchanged-group-format='' --new-group-format='+++%>' file.txt file2.txt
***line 4b
+++line 6
```